# iOS 8 - Disable iCloud Photo Sharing Activity

Tags: ios, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

Apparently iOS8 by default adds a "iCloud Photo Sharing" activity to activity views in iOS8 and I haven't found any useful documentation regarding it, especially how to explicitly remove it (going into the "More" option allows the user to toggle showing/hiding it, but for our app we want to completely disallow this option).

Has anyone figured anything out about how to disable this? Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Activity VC with unwanted "iCloud Photo Sharing" option]

[image: "More" option with user-performed manual enable/disable]

Comment: FYI - I'd like to remove "iCloud Photo Sharing" as well. I tried adding the following string values but none of them worked. "com.apple.UIKit.activity.iCloudPhotoSharing", "com.apple.UIKit.activity.PhotoSharing", "com.apple.UIKit.activity.ICloudPhotoSharing", "com.apple.UIKit.activity.iCloud", "com.apple.UIKit.activity.iCloudPhoto", "com.apple.UIKit.activity.iCloudSharing", "iCloudPhotoSharing".

Comment: The `activityType` is `@"com.apple.mobileslideshow.StreamShareService"`. However this does nothing when added to the excludes list.

Comment: **Easily done here** ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/37217699/294884

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude Notes and Reminders apps from the UIActivityViewController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792506/how-to-exclude-notes-and-reminders-apps-from-the-uiactivityviewcontroller)

Answer (score 6):

If you init your UIActivityViewController with full of images, iCloud sharing set to activity types by default. You can add a string in your activityItems array. This move will cause that iCloud sharing to be removed from activityTypes.

```
NSArray *Items   = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: image1, image2, @"", nil];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:Items applicationActivities:nil];
```

Comment: Mildly hacky solution, but it works.  This is especially if you use a `UIActivityItemSource` and want image type activities to show up

Comment: Then have to exclude `UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard`, as that will just copy the empty string.

Comment: You can keep pasteboard functionality if you replace the empty string activity item with a custom UIActivityItemProvider that returns a nil item and has an empty string as its placeholder item.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you'd set the `excludedActivityTypes` property on your `UIActivityViewController` instance -- e.g., to exclude posting to Facebook, you'd put `UIActivityTypePostToFacebook` in that array.

But it doesn't look like the [Built-in Activity Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Built_in_Activity_Types) list (either in the documentation or in `UIActiviy.h`) includes a constant for iCloud Photos. That's probably worth [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) about.