# Why cannot remove Gmail from UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to remove Gmail from my UIActivityViewController. Here is my following code:

```
ActivityViewController *activityVC = [[ActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
    NSLog(@"%@", activityType);
};

NSArray *excludeActivities = @[@"com.google.Gmail.ShareExtension"];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But Gmail is still there! Anyone has advise how to remove?

**Note**

I get `com.google.Gmail.ShareExtension` from the printed log

Comment: see this may be help with you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522977/uiactivityviewcontroller-exclude-non-apple-sharing-extensions

Comment: http://johnszumski.com/blog/excluding-third-party-apps-from-ios-8-share-sheet

Comment: radar shows its closed but unable to work for some thirdparties

Comment: I see! I didn't find about it earlier. Thanks!!