# What is the UIActivityType for Notes?

Tags: ios9, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to exclude all services from my UIActivityType except for email and text message.  I am using the following statement:

```
activityController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,UIActivityTypeAirDrop,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                                     UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
                                                     UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,UIActivityTypePrint,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];
```

Under iOS 9 I notice that there is something called "Notes" that also shows up.  I have looked in the Apple documentation as well as autocomplete and cannot find an entry that references Notes.  How can I exclude it?

Comment: File a bug report on this. Apple neglected to provide a way to exclude the Notes app.

Comment: Filed report.  We'll see what happens...

Comment: I'll tell you what happens. It will be closed as a duplicate just as mine was. But this is good. The more Apple hears that developers need this, the better chance it has of being resolved.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792506/how-to-exclude-notes-and-reminders-apps-from-the-uiactivityviewcontroller/32719521#32719521

Comment: @rmaddy any update on excluding the Notes app? Still doesn't seem possible on iOS 10 ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude Notes and Reminders apps from the UIActivityViewController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792506/how-to-exclude-notes-and-reminders-apps-from-the-uiactivityviewcontroller)