# Exclude activities in activity view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I would like to exclude "Notes" and "Save PDF to iBooks" in my activity view controller. Is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude Notes and Reminders apps from the UIActivityViewController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792506/how-to-exclude-notes-and-reminders-apps-from-the-uiactivityviewcontroller)

Comment: I need a solution that wouldn't risk not passing apple's validation

Comment: In that link it is given from iOS 9 it's not possible 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792506/how-to-exclude-notes-and-reminders-apps-from-the-uiactivityviewcontroller/32719521#32719521

Another link like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707106/what-is-the-uiactivitytype-for-notes

Both link shows it's not possible for now to remove note directly in iOS 9