# willBeginSendingToApplication not called when open EverNote or any other extention

Tags: ios, ipad, uidocumentinteraction

I have a feature to open docs in other apps from iPhone and iPad app.
Also a flag is set whether to allow this action or not. Few apps can be white listed.

When any app is chosen to open doc

```
- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller willBeginSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application
```

is called.

In this method I can check whether to allow for chosen app or not.

Issue is for Note, Evernote we get two options 1- its extension 2- Open in.
Above method is called for 2 option.
But extensions are launched directly.

I din't found any other delegate method called for this.

Comment: Got same issue in MobileIron support. https://community.mobileiron.com/docs/DOC-2001

Comment: Thank you for the MobileIron document. We are facing the exact same issue here at SecurePIM. I am interested if apple will provide some fix for this.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you figured something out, but my org faced a similar issue and the MDMs we work with don't have an easy solution. We've decided on the following approach.

- Always use `UIDocumentInteractionController` instead of `UIActivityViewController`
- Whenever `UIDocumentInteractionController` is opened reinit and set the URL to dummy content
- Conform to `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` and check the `application` parameter in `willBeginSendingToApplication` against your whitelist
- If `application` is part of the whitelist then change the value of `controller.url` to the correct content

The downsides of this approach are that only open-in will work (extensions will always get dummy content) and the user experience isn't great. But if you're building an enterprise app and must prevent data leakage then this is probably the safest way to go.

You can also check out this article for private APIs to hide third-party apps and extensions, mostly in `UIActivityViewController`:

[How to exclude Notes and Reminders apps from the UIActivityViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792506/how-to-exclude-notes-and-reminders-apps-from-the-uiactivityviewcontroller)

Unfortunately the way this works seems to have changed between iOS 8 and 9, and again with 10, so it's not optimal. I recommend passing dummy content.