# iOS Swift - How to assign a default action to all buttons programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, user-experience

I'm working with an app in prototype stage of development. Some interface elements do not have any action assigned to them either through storyboard or programmatically.

According to UX guidelines, I want to find these "inactive" buttons in app and have them display a "feature not available" alert when tapped during testing. Can this be done through an extension of UIButton?

**How can I assign a default action to UIButton to show an alert unless another action is assigned via interface builder or programmatically?**

Comment: I would suggest to follow the approach of *method swizzling*.

Comment: Please check out my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well what you are trying to achieve can be done. I have done this using a `UIViewController` extension and adding a closure as the target of a button which does not have a target. In case the button does not have an action an alert is presented.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.checkButtonAction()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    }
    @IBAction func btn_Action(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }

}

extension UIViewController{
    func checkButtonAction(){
        for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
            if let btn = view as? UIButton {
                if (btn.allTargets.isEmpty){
                    btn.add(for: .touchUpInside, {
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Test 3", message:"No selector", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                        // add an action (button)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

                        // show the alert
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    })
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
class ClosureSleeve {
    let closure: ()->()

    init (_ closure: @escaping ()->()) {
        self.closure = closure
    }

    @objc func invoke () {
        closure()
    }
}

extension UIControl {
    func add (for controlEvents: UIControlEvents, _ closure: @escaping ()->()) {
        let sleeve = ClosureSleeve(closure)
        addTarget(sleeve, action: #selector(ClosureSleeve.invoke), for: controlEvents)
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, String(format: "[%d]", arc4random()), sleeve, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    }
}
```

I have tested it. Hope this helps. Happy coding.

Answer (score 4):

As you cannot override methods in extensions, the only remaining options are:
1. subclass your buttons - but probably not what you're looking for, because I assume you want to use this functionality for already existing buttons
2. method swizzling - to change the implementation of existing function, i.e. `init`

Comment: If you end up swizzling you might have to swizzle `initWithCoder` as well, as this would be invoked for buttons added in interface builder.

Comment: I see this answer on swizzling, but still don't know how to use that code to assign a selector to buttons. However, my knowledge of swift3 is not enough to make it assign a custom action to buttons. How do I do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562887/how-to-implement-method-swizzling-swift-3-0

Answer (score 1):

> How can I assign a default action to UIButton to show an alert unless
>   another action is assigned via interface builder or programmatically?

I would suggest to do *method swizzling*:

> Through swizzling, the implementation of a method can be replaced with
>   a different one at runtime, by changing the mapping between a specific
>   selector(method) and the function that contains its implementation.

<sub>https://www.uraimo.com/2015/10/23/effective-method-swizzling-with-swift/</sub>

*Remark: I would recommend to check the article above.*

As an exact answer for your question, the following code snippet should be -in general- what are you trying to achieve:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK:- IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var lblMessage: UILabel!

    // MARK:- IBActions
    @IBAction func applySwizzlingTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        swizzleButtonAction()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Original!")
        lblMessage.text = "Original!"
    }
}

extension ViewController {
    func swizzleButtonAction() {
        let originalSelector = #selector(buttonTapped(_:))
        let swizzledSelector = #selector(swizzledAction(_:))

        let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(ViewController.self, originalSelector)
        let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(ViewController.self, swizzledSelector)

        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
    }

    func swizzledAction(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Swizzled!")
        lblMessage.text = "Swizzled!"
    }
}
```

After calling `swizzleButtonAction()` -by tapping the "Apply Swizzling" button (`applySwizzlingTapped`)-, the selector of "Button" should changed from `buttonTapped` to `swizzledAction`.

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this kind of function by using IBOutlet collection variable, and then removing buttons from that collection as soon as the feature is implemented. something like this:

```
class ViewController {
    @IBOutlet var inactiveBtns: [UIButton]!

    func viewDidLoad() {
        inactiveBtns.forEach { (button) in
           button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showDialog), for: UIControlEvents())
        }
    }

    func showDialog() {
        // show the dialog
    }
}
```

That IBOutlet is visible in the interface builder, so you can add multiple buttons in there.

Comment: By this way we need to do in all controllers & also have to update if anything modified.

Comment: I've considered such solution, but I can't see myself implementing it, as it would touch multiple storyboards and cause merge conflicts with other developers.