# Swift 4 + swizzle viewWillAppear()

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift4, swizzling

My question is not about how to swizzle, but rather what is happening in this particular code snippet:

```
private let swizzling: (UIViewController.Type) -> () = { viewController in

    let originalSelector = #selector(viewController.viewWillAppear(_:))
    let swizzledSelector = #selector(viewController.proj_viewWillAppear(animated:))

    let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(viewController, originalSelector)
    let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(viewController, swizzledSelector)

    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod) }

extension UIViewController {

    open override class func initialize() {
        // make sure this isn't a subclass
        guard self === UIViewController.self else { return }
        swizzling(self)
    }

    // MARK: - Method Swizzling

    func proj_viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.proj_viewWillAppear(animated: animated)

        let viewControllerName = NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
        print("viewWillAppear: \(viewControllerName)")
    } 
 }
```

This code sniper is from here: [Swizzling CocoaTouch class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562887/how-to-implement-method-swizzling-swift-3-0)

The question I have is around the following line of code:

```
// make sure this isn't a subclass
guard self === UIViewController.self else { return }
```

Why do we need to check if it isn't a subclass of UIViewController? My scenario is I want to send analytics data with view name to Omniture (on ever viewWillAppear). If I do the check, the swizzling never works, yet when I comment this line out, I get my desired result, and every view controller sends data.

Comment: Then comment it out. Your needs are different from the needs of the code that you used as a model. Unclear what the question is, since you seem already to know the answer!

Comment: @matt it seems that all the swift examples i looked at have this line in them, so there is some significance to that. That is what I am trying to understand

Comment: I believe otherwise all UIViewController viewWillAppear will be swizzled regardless of the subclass in question... although I do not understand why this would be the case. Although I am not sure that this works with Swift 4

Answer (score 2):

The examples you've looked at seem to come from the days when this was done in the class `initialize` method, where you have to make that check or you can end up running the same code multiple times (when a subclass is used for the first time), which results in your swizzling an already swizzled method.

But the `initialize` method is no longer permitted in Swift, so that line doesn't apply.