# Listen to UIViewController presentation event

Tags: swift

I want to know how does analytic frameworks detect screen transition?
Like showing or presenting ViewController?

What I want to do is listening to all ViewController presentation event and check the view identifier. If the view identifier is of a special kind. I will do an additional step, such as tracking the view's presented time.

I remember that few years ago, you can do this (listen to presentation event), but I forgot if it was part of NotificationCenter or Darwin...

Currently, I think the only "Documented" way of doing this is by specifying completion block on `present()` function call. But that would mean I have to modify every call, and I want to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

One approach (I think Firebase are doing something similar with their analytics SDK) is to swizzle the `viewDidLoad` and run the checks you intend

Some Examples - [link - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47538224/swift-4-swizzle-viewwillappear), [link 2](https://abhimuralidharan.medium.com/method-swizzling-in-ios-swift-1f38edaf984f), [link 3](https://medium.com/@giovannipalusa/swizzle-viewwilldisappear-to-abort-loaders-in-swift-5-d5c58c823d61)

Another could be to use a base class that will override this method and run the checks you would like....

```
class BaseViewContoller: UIViewContoller {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   // check whatever you'd with
  }
}

....

final class MyActualViewController: BaseViewController {
  ....
}
```