# Detect UIViewController changed in Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, notificationcenter

For analytics purposes, I would like to detect whenever the top UIViewController is modified.
I **don't** want to use inheritance, but rather delegate some event that I can use.
I see that Firebase have some type of mechanism for that but I couldn't figure how exactly.
Something like the following will be great:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(topViewModified), name: .TopViewModified, object: nil)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use swizzling for `viewDidAppear` method where you will post notification about view controller appearing

Comment: I believe as Taras mentioned, without subclassing you need to swizzle the viewDidAppear or something similar as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562887/how-to-implement-method-swizzling-swift-3-0.