# @_dynamicReplacement(for: ) error in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I use CocoaPods to manage my private components. Now I have a component `Test`. The declaration of one of the classes is as follows:

```swift
open class Test {

    open dynamic func test() {
        print("test")
    }
}
```

I have no problems with this component, it is already in my private repo

Now I have another component called `Test2`. I want to use `@_dynamicReplacement(for:)` in `Test2` to exchange the `test()` method in Test as follows:

```swift
public extension Test {

    @_dynamicReplacement(for: test())
    public func test2() {
        print("test2")
    }
}
```

Now I want to package Test2 as a pod component, like Test.

But when I execute `pod spec lint`, it reports an error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: fatal error encountered during compilation; please file a bug report with your project and the crash log
<unknown>:0: note: unsupported relocation with subtraction expression, symbol '_$s9MBCRouter6RouterC23MBCNavigationController0cdB010NavigationORszrlE15navigationTest2yyF' can not be undefined in a subtraction expression
```

---

I found that this problem only appeared on `x86_64` on `i386`.

I tried to create a project that integrates both `Test` and `Test2`.

When I run it on a real machine, it works fine. But when **I run it on the simulator**, it reports an error!

When I placed the second piece of code above in the Test component, it worked without any problems.

So I think the following two conditions are needed to reproduce this bug:

1. In `pod B`, use `@_dynamicReplacement(for:)` to swap methods in other pod components
2. Run the project in the simulator

I found this problem, but I can't solve it, can anyone help to solve this problem? thank you very much!

---

Finally, I want to talk about my development environment

1. I use CocoaPods 1.9.1, Xcode 11.4 and Swift 5.2.
2. Only `use_frameworks!` is used in the podfile
3. `Test` and `Test2` `.podspec` files with set `static_framework = true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build for Simulator you need add `@objc` attribute to a function declaration e.g:

```
open class Test {

    open @objc dynamic func test() {
        print("test")
    }
}
```

UPDATE: More common solution (included Generics) - set **Compilation Mode** to **Incremental** in Build Settings and in this case you don't need to use `@objc` at all for the Simulator.

Comment: thank! It is useful! But unfortunately, it cannot be applied to classes with generics, so sad

Comment: Is there any way to make classes with generics also use `@_dynamicReplacement` under the simulator? e.g. `class Test <T: Codable>`

Comment: I' found a solution: you should set **Compilation Mode** to **Incremental** in Build Settings to compile generics with `@_dynamicReplacement` for Simulator.

Comment: After adding `@objc`, I cannot use `-Xfrontend -enable-dynamic-replacement-chaining` to perform multiple replacement operations on the same method. Only one method will take effect. When I remove `@objc`, all methods will be executed ...

Comment: For **Incremental** mode you don't need to use `@objc` at all.

Comment: I have a compilation error `'myMethod' is marked @objc dynamic`, `Extensions of generic classes cannot contain '@objc' members` after adding the `@_dynamicReplacement`