# IOS UIActivityViewController, Can not exclude custom activityType

Tags: ios, swift, share-extension, ios-sharesheet

I made my own share extension and also my app sharing something with UIActivityViewController.
But it was not cool, my own share-extension shows up when I am sharing something.
So I want exclude my own share-extension, but it is not working.
I double-checked my app name, it was correct.

Here is my code.

```
let activityItems = [shareUrl]
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)

activityViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = ["com.mytest.ShareExtension"]; 
activityViewController.completionHandler = { (activityType: String?, completed: Bool) -> Void in

    print(activityType) // printed "com.mytest.ShareExtension"
}

vc.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792506/how-to-exclude-notes-and-reminders-apps-from-the-uiactivityviewcontroller) helps. It states that subclassing the UIActivityViewController and overwriting the

`- (BOOL)_shouldExcludeActivityType:(UIActivity *)activity`

Method should do the trick. For me it did, and some say, it's AppStore Approved.
And Swift is compatible to Objective-C via Bridging-Headers. 
Hope it helps.