# is it possible to exclude Notes and Reminders safely from the UIActivityViewController in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I tried before using the answers in this post -

[How to exclude Notes and Reminders apps from the UIActivityViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792506/how-to-exclude-notes-and-reminders-apps-from-the-uiactivityviewcontroller)

But none of them worked for me.
Does anyone know if there is an options to remove them in iOS 10?
or a better solution that will work for me in iOS 9 ? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
NSString *text = @"XYZ";
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ABC"];
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[text, image] applicationActivities:nil];

controller.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                     UIActivityTypeMail,
                                     UIActivityTypePrint,
                                     UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                     UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                     UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                     UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                     UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                     UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                                     UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,
                                     UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                     UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks,
                                     @"com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension",
                                     @"com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension"];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```