# how to show only facebook,twitter and email in UIactivity viewcontroller in ios (objective c)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have an app I need to display only facebook,twitter and email in activityview controller?

everything need exclude.

How can I do that?

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can exclude lots of system provided activities by setting the appropriate `excludedActivityTypes`.

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792506/how-to-exclude-notes-and-reminders-apps-from-the-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: Cannot. You can custom ur own view though.

Answer (score 3):

To exclude everything:

```
NSArray *exclude = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
                     UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
                     UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                     UIActivityTypeMessage,
                     UIActivityTypeMail,
                     UIActivityTypePrint,
                     UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                     UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                     UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                     UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                     UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                     UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                     UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,
                     UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                     UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks];

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = exclude;
```

Remove Facebook, Twitter and Mail from the list to show them in the action sheet.

Comment: need to show only facebook,twitter and email... other third party don't want to display

Comment: Just exclude items that you want to show in list from that array. @Maulik

Comment: I think I see your problem - only iOS integrated services are 'excludable' using `excludedActivityTypes`. Therefore other apps (WhatsApp, LinkedIn, Instagram) will not be excluded. The array seems to be a list of share extension bundle IDs (e.g. Messages has identifier `com.apple.UIKit.activity.Message`). If you know the identifiers of the other apps you want to exclude, you _might_ be able to add them to the list. I haven't tried this, so not sure if it will work.

Comment: Have just tried excluding 'com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension' (which is the ActivityType that gets returned when you share with LinkedIn) and can confirm it does NOT work. I think you'll have to roll your own and integrate with the FB, Twitter and mail SDKs.