# How can you customize UIActivityViewController to ONLY include custom UIActivity types?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to customize the native ios `UIActivityViewController` so it will restrict every `UIActivity` except for the custom `UIActivity` types that I initialize the UIActivityViewController with.

Essentially, I only want the user to see my four custom `UIActivity`s.

```
let items = ["Hello world"]

let activitySheet = CustomUIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: items,
            applicationActivities: [
                CustomMailUIActivity(),
                CustomMessagesUIActivity(),
                CustomTwitterUIActivity(),
                CustomFacebookUIActivity()
            ]
        )
```

I understand that you can use `activitySheet.excludedActivityTypes = []` to exclude types that you do not need, however you are not able to exclude third party applications such as Slack.

I was wondering if there was any way to get around that and ONLY include custom `applicationActivies`. It would also be great to remove the "More" button that appears on the share sheet as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I'm trying to achieve.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YK8I.png)

Comment: Unfortunately `UIActivityViewController ` doesn't make this easy. You need to list all of the activities you wish to exclude and some can't be excluded. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792506/how-to-exclude-notes-and-reminders-apps-from-the-uiactivityviewcontroller for some ideas to get close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My colleague was able to figure this out. For anyone wondering how to display **only** the `applicationActivities` (custom activities) on the share sheet, this is how I did it.

For `activityItems` rather than creating an array of strings, create an array of your custom data objects. Then override the `canPerform(withActivityItems activityItems: [Any])` method in your custom `UIActivity` (subclass of `UIActivity`) to return true if `activityItems[o] is CustomItem`. Since your `activityItems` are custom, system will not display other apps on the share sheet. That's it.

In the example below, only your `CustomUIActivity` will be displayed on the share sheet.

```
let items = [CustomItem("Hello world")]

let activitySheet = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: items,
            applicationActivities: [
                CustomUIActivity()
            ]
        )
```

```
class CustomItem {

    let value: String

    required init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func getValue() -> String {
        return self.value
    }
}
```

```
@objc(CustomUIActivity)
class CustomUIActivity: UIActivity {

    override class var activityCategory: UIActivity.Category {
        return .share
    }

    override var activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType? {
        return .customuiactivity
    }

    override var activityTitle: String? {
        return "Custom"
    }

    override var activityImage: UIImage? {
        return UIImage(named: "custom-icon")
    }

    override func canPerform(withActivityItems activityItems: [Any]) -> Bool {
        if activityItems.count == 1 && activityItems[0] is CustomItem {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    var textToShare: String?

    override func prepare(withActivityItems activityItems: [Any]) {
        if let activityItem = activityItems.first as? CustomItem {
            self.textToShare = activityItem.getValue
        }
    }

    override func perform() {
        // perform your custom activity with `textToShare`
        activityDidFinish(true)
    }
}

extension UIActivity.ActivityType {
    static let customuiactivity =
        UIActivity.ActivityType("com.ceylonese.mobile.customuiactivity")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Did you also figure out how to only show actions? So something that looks like the e.g. "Copy"-Action on a regular UIActivityViewController?

Comment: If I want to share content using only some 2-3 apps, say Gmail, WhatsApp and Mail app.. is it possible using this approach? Thanks