# Remove third party apps from uiactivityviewcontroller iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

Is there any way to hide third party apps extension in UIActivityViewController sheet? Only able to exclude apple predefined app extension. Please suggest me.

I just want to show only Airdrop, Mail and Print options in UIActivityViewController. Hide other installed apps in device i.e) Wattsapp.

Comment: Can you give more details? Maybe provide some images of what you mean.

Comment: check it out...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151619/how-can-you-customize-uiactivityviewcontroller-to-only-include-custom-uiactivity

Comment: I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792506/how-to-exclude-notes-and-reminders-apps-from-the-uiactivityviewcontroller) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55302714/5928311) should helps you.