# iOS - Is it possible to have a Custom Uniform Type that only your app can open? (Remove other apps from Open In menu)

Tags: ios, xcode

We currently have a suite that consists of 2 in house apps. Both these apps let you create custom files in a propriety format only these apps would understand. I'm basically writing a system for App A to create a file and share it with App B.

I've been able to setup a custom file format (.custom for example) with custom mime, "CUSTOM/CUSTOM".

I can create the files and then do a share dialog with this file format.

App B registers the Custom Uniform Type like so...

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>My Transfer File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.my.company.custom</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>My Transfer File</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.my.company.custom</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>custom</string>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>company/custom</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

This works. When I share the file from App A the share dialog opens and 'Copy to App B' is one of the options...

But so are a few others still..

AirDrop, Messages, Mail, Facebook Messenger, WhatsApp

They all get listed before our Copy To App B.

I imagine we can't get rid of AirDrop, Messages and mail, but Facebook and Whatsapp are somewhat annoying to be listed first.

Is there a way to create a Uniform Type Identifier to get around this? Is it the UITypeConformsTo thats causing this?

EDIT: After further investigation, I believe I am doing things right, but there's nothing I can really do to remove apps from the Share Sheet. I think it boils down to the fact some apps claim they can handle *any* files. Your Custom Uniform Type *has* to have a 'Conforms To' field, and even setting it to the base type of public.data or public.item, apps like DropBox, WhatsApp, Messenger etc I 'think' claim they can handle any public.data or public.item app, so will appear in the list.

So instead I just implemented App Group usage and I store the files I want to transfer in the shared container. Its nicer code wise and nicer UI wise (no dialogs)....its just a horrid pain setting up as is everything to do with Provisioning profiles and certificates!

Maybe one day it will be possible and an Answer will get put against this question.

Comment: Ok, so I've removed a lot of options used the  Excluded Activity Types.

AirDrop, Message, Mail, PostToFacebook and CopyToPasteboard are removed.

But Messenger and WhatsApp are still options for opening my custom file type....but how? Its a useless file type to those apps so why do they think they can open them?

Comment: Tried on another device which has DropBox and Chrome an they appear too. Even tapping on Chrome will then say, 'Chrome cannot handle this link." and displays teh file://blah/MyFile.custom

So why does the iOS add it to the share sheet?

I'm thinking i've not setup Import Type UTIs, Export Type UTIs and Document Types in the plist files correctly.

Which ones do I add to App A (exporting) and App B (importing, the app I want to be in the Share Sheet) ?

Comment: This might work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55302714/6257435

Comment: If I'm right in reading that, that seems to be how to get App A to only display activities inside App A in the Share Screen?

I'm not sure how to get App A to only show App B in the share screen.

Have I understood that solution right? It looks like the custom activity has to be inside the same app as the share process, where as I want App B to be shown.

I'm also transferring a file from one app to another so not sure how that would work with this CustomItem wrapper idea...

Comment: Sorry... I had done some searching, and most answers come up with "can't do it." Came across that one and, without close reading, sounded like it might do the job. Another option - certainly not as good as using a share sheet - would be to use App Group shared defaults (although I expect you're already familiar with that).

Comment: Yeah i'm aware of the App Group shared folder system, the current apps have Share sheet integration already so I was hoping it would 'just work' with that....I've got it implemented at least and working (just with other apps in the list) so I think I'm going to just switch over and try out App Grouping for now.

Cheers!