# how to share only through email using UIActivityViewController using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

```
 let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController (activityItems: contentArray, applicationActivities:nil)
        if let popoverController = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
            popoverController.sourceView = sender

        }
        self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

So basically I want to share the content only through mail and I do not want to show the option of message. 
Could you help me out with that. Also I want to set the subject of the email through the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add excludedActivityTypes to remove all the other activity except email

```
yourActivityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,UIActivityTypeAirDrop]
```

Add subject

```
 yourActivityViewController.setValue("Your email Subject" , forKey: "subject") ;
```

**Suggession :-**
You can also use MFMailComposeViewController to send email

```
 var picker = MFMailComposeViewController()
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self
    picker.setSubject(subject.text)
    picker.setMessageBody(body.text, isHTML: true)

    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

More References :-
[How do I use UIActivityItemProvider to send an email with attachment with UIActivityViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581389/how-do-i-use-uiactivityitemprovider-to-send-an-email-with-attachment-with-uiacti)

[iOS 8 - Disable iCloud Photo Sharing Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796125/ios-8-disable-icloud-photo-sharing-activity)

Comment: By using UIActivityController will I be able to add the subject of the email

Comment: How to hide the "Notes" in sharing option?

Comment: This doesn't hide other third party apps (e.g. Whatsapp)

Comment: Swift 4: `yourActivityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.postToFacebook, UIActivityType.postToTwitter, UIActivityType.postToWeibo, UIActivityType.message, UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard,UIActivityType.assignToContact,UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.postToFlickr, UIActivityType.postToVimeo,UIActivityType.postToTencentWeibo,UIActivityType.airDrop]`